# EF Core IN Equivalent

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

What would be the LINQ equivalent to this:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyItems] WHERE [MyItems].[TheStatus] IN (3,5,14,23)
```

I tried something like this:

```
DbContext.MyItems.Where(mi => statuses.Contains(mi.TheStatus));
```

Comment: You can do it using multiple || statements:
DbContext.MyItems.Where(mi => mi.TheStatus == 3 || mi.TheStatus == 5 || mi.TheStatus == 14 || mi.TheStatus == 23));

Keep in mind that IN is not more efficient than multiple ORs in SQL.

Comment: What's the problem with your attempt (because that's indeed the `IN` equivalent)?

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the response, but the status list is dynamic and is a variable and not hard-coded as I've included in my example.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, It would appear that my post was premature as after inspecting my results (returning 9 instead of the 4 that I specified), there is another property in the table that is not being filtered for some reason and that is the actual problem.  The "IN" does in fact work and I guess this can be ignored.

Comment: And upon further review, this was working from the beginning.  I had a script that was executing that was inserting duplicate records in my table.  Apologies guys and really do appreciate the prompt responses.